# Is it possible to get facebook login status using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page with Facebook connect button. After the user clics on the button and grants the required permission, I need to check the login status.

Is it possible to do that without using javascript ? probably using the Graph API.

I'm using APEX and the page contents will depend on whether the user is connected to my app or not.

For info the user is asked to connect to my app using login page :

https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=www.example.com&scope=public_profile,email,user_friends

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Older versions of the PHP SDK (v3, not sure if that was still present in v4, def. not in v5) had a method to generate a URL for this specific purpose. You would redirect the user there in their browser, and it would redirect straight back, appending the current status info as a GET parameter. Not sure if those URLs still work (undocumented stuff might break at any time) - but if you are interested, you could try and find the old SDK code somewhere, and check what the specific URL for this purpose was/is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, but using the Javascript SDK is encouraged for web applications.   See Facebook's documentation for [implementing login on other platforms](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow), specifically when dealing with browsers that don't support Javascript.